# Should tuples be transposed if they are interpreted as columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, notation

I've recently come across some papers, where authors write things like $(1,2,3)^\mathsf{T}$ to refer to the column vector $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix},$$
and avoid confusion with rows (row vectors). 
I had always been under the impression that commas "$,$" are to be interpreted as "new lines", and an $n$-tuple is automatically treated as an $n\times 1$ (not $1\times n$ vector). I would personally denote a row vector as $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}$ rather than $(1,2,3)$. Thus adopting my convention, it is perfectly acceptable to say something like: "if $\mathbf x = (1,2,3)$, then $\mathbf{Ax}=(4,5,6)$", where $\mathbf A$ is some $3\times3$ matrix, with out needing any $^\mathsf{T}$ symbols.

I was then told that $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}$ can be interpreted as a cycle permutation, but I don't think that there is really room for confusion there. What do you think? What is the "standard" interpretation of $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: I don't think whitespace is a good delimiter in general

Comment: @Klangen Aren't all entries in a matrix separated by a whitespace? Surely we only care about the difference between rows and columns where we are talking about matrices.

Comment: It is a matter of convention, but also of readibility. In the vertical writing we do not have commas simply because we are not at risk of reading $(1 \ 2 \ 3 )$ as the single number $123$.

Comment: I expect $(x,y,z)$ to be a tuple or a vector (including a matrix) depending on the context. The only difference between them is the additional algebraic structure a vector space provides but that's contextual information. Without commas I would assume it's a cycle of a permutation unless it has square brackets instead of rounded brackets.

Comment: I don't think I've ever encountered the interpretation that commas are to be interpreted as new lines. In particular, if you told me that $(1\ 2\ 3)(1,2,3)$ is a scalar but $(1,2,3)(1\ 2\ 3)$ is a $3\times3$ matrix I would be very confused.

Comment: It's easier to be a little pedantic and explicit, than to risk potential misunderstandings based on notational interpretations.

Comment: My main point with this question is that I think it is acceptable to write $\mathbf x = (x,y,z)$, and subsequently write $\mathbf {Ax}$, without having to insert a $^\mathsf{T}$ anywhere. I would use this purely inline; in display math, I will still write $$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix},$$ and never misleading things like $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}(1,2,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Defining $K^3$ as the set of tuples $(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z\in K$ and then later on writing these as columns $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is common practice to allow multiplying elements of $K^3$ with $3\times 3$ matrices from the left. However, it doesn't hurt to write $(x,y,z)^t$ explicitly when you want to point out to the reader that this should be a column vector and you only write it as a tuple to save space.

I don't think I've heard about the convention "commas in tuples mean new lines" in that wording, instead I'd say we just use both tuples and columns vectors to denote elements of $K^n$.

Comment: I’ve often seen explicit transpose symbols elided in order to reduce clutter.